# Intervention/image Change text size/font mid-phrase

Tags: intervention

I've got this image where I want to put right-aligned text, but the text is formed as follow :

- a label, very small in size, with a fixed content
- a value, which can change in length (an integer between 0 and 100)

For the moment, i managed to make two `text` calls, but when the value lengths changes, the two texs overlap.

Is there a way to tell intervention/image to change font & size mid-phrase ? Or is my approach the bad one ?

Edit #1:

My current code :

```
<?php
/**
 * StackOverflow test
 *
 * @param  int                  $int
 * @return Intervention\Image
 */
public function stackOverflow($int)
{
    $img = Image::canvas(200, 50, '#FF0000');

    $img->text('Label', 130, 30, function ($font) {
        $font->file(resource_path('assets/fonts/futura-medium.ttf'));
        $font->size(18);
    });

    $img->text($int, 190, 30, function ($font) {
        $font->file(resource_path('assets/fonts/futura-medium.ttf'));
        $font->size(30);
        $font->align('right');
    });

    return $img->response('png');
}
```

With a $int parameter of 10, the display is correct :

[image: Two-digit int is okay]

When the $int parameter exceeds 99, the number overlaps the label :

[image: With a three-digit number, it overlaps the label]

And whe the $int parameter is below 10, the label is too far away from its value :

[image]

I'd want to find a way to keep the label at the same distance of the integer value (Maybe by knowing the integer width after display ?)

Edit #2

Checking the string length would be a workaround, but as I work with non fixed-width font, the results are still inconsistent :

[image: With narrow numbers, the label is far from them]

[image: With wide numbers, the label is very near]

Answer (score 0):

Intervention image text has a call back which allow you to do some fine adjustments so you can use for the label:

```
$img->text('The label', 20, 50);
```

This method with a call back for your value, or this method for both:

```
$img->text('Te value', 0, 0, function($font) {
    $font->file('fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf');
    $font->size(24);
    $font->color('#fdf6e3');
    $font->align('center');  //left, right or center. 
    $font->valign('top');    //top, bottom or middle. 
    $font->angle(45);
});
```

You can use all the options or only the one you need.

In this way you will have much more control when positioning the text.

I hope this will help you out. I am using this method with intervention in codeigniter

**EDIT: Following the comment and additional info you have posted.**

Check the length of your value and assign it to a variable:

Please note that I have added just some imaginary position values.

```
if(strlen($int) == 1){
   $pos = 195;  // this is the position of your label you need to adjust it
}elseif(strlen($int) == 2){
   $pos = 190;  //pos label you need to adjust it
}elseif(strlen($int) == 3){
   $pos = 185;  //pos label you need to adjust it
}
```

Pass the variable to the label $img->text();

```
$img->text('The label', $pos, 30, function($font) {
```

The label will be dynamically positioned according to the length of your value.

Comment: Thanks, but you missed the point (Maybe I didn't give sufficient details, I'll edit the question further)

Comment: You can make a conditional statement in your code before assign the position: Let's say, you first count the length  of your value and if this is 1 set the position to 195, it is is  2 set the position to 190 and if this is 3 set it to 185. Assign those values to a $pos variable  and pass it to the function `$img->text('Label', $pos, 30, function ($font) {` so that the position will be applied dinamically

Comment: Please also note that the position values I have mentioned  are just imaginary, You need to set the proper values trying out which one will fit your layout.

Comment: Yes, that would be a better solution, but mostly with fixed-width fonts.

Comment: With this approach you can change everything. In place of hard code the values just set your variables in the `if` conditions and pass the variables to the $img->text()

Comment: You mean I should calculate all my numbers' width? Or I didn't understand your answer.

Comment: No, If your value is one digit `strlen($int) == 1`, set the position of the label accordingly in the `$pos` variable. The same if there are 2 digit or 3 digit. The flexibility of this is that you can add more conditionals. I am using this also all the time to get my layout consistent. You do this one time and don't have to worry anymore.

Comment: As I said, this will cause different spaces between the label and the numbers, depending on the digit's width.

Comment: Marc, every digit width i.e. `strlen()` has  his own `$pos` variable. You need to assign the value to this variable to every `strlen()` which will position the label at the correct point you want to. This will work for sure. Unfortunately I can not post for you an example because there are to much dependencies otherwise I would do it for you. Just trust me and try to understand how this works. The only thing you have to do is just implement it in your code and adjust the `$pos` value

Comment: About the font-size you need to set for both `label and value` the same value to display the two elements correctly. I have had in the past the same problem and I couldn't find any solution. That's why I use this method.